# ¿Cómo ejecuto un método al presionar una tecla en ASP:NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net

Buenas a todos, quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de ejecutar un método al presionar una tecla cualquiera en ASP.NET.

Tengo este método que carga la información desde la base de datos

```
protected void Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb_ResultadoFiltro.Items.Clear();
    Info_Empleado obj = new Info_Empleado();
    obj.Id_Estado = 4;
    if (Modal_txtCedulaResp.Text != "") 
    { 
        obj.N_Identificacion = Modal_txtCedulaResp.Text; 
    }
    if (Modal_txtNombresResp.Text != "") 
    { 
        obj.Nombres = Modal_txtNombresResp.Text; 
    }
    if (Modal_txtApellidosResp.Text != "") 
    { 
        obj.Apellido1 = Modal_txtApellidosResp.Text; 
    }
    if (Modal_txtCargoResp.Text != "") 
    { 
        obj.Cargo = Modal_txtCargoResp.Text; 
    }
    DataTable dt = Info_Empleado_BRL.SelectTable(obj, 3);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            li.Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            li.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + " | " + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][3].ToString() + " | " + dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
            lb_ResultadoFiltro.Items.Add(li);
        }
    }
}
```

este es el HTML del modal

```
<div id="modalBuscarResponsable" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Busqueda</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">           
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table style=" width:60%; margin:auto;">
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5>Cédula</h5></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Modal_txtCedulaResp" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)" runat="server" onkeydown="filtrar()" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5>Nombres</h5></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Modal_txtNombresResp" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" OnTextChanged="Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5>Apellidos</h5></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Modal_txtApellidosResp" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" OnTextChanged="Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h5>Cargo</h5></td>
                                <td><asp:TextBox ID="Modal_txtCargoResp" Width="100%" CssClass="form-control" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" OnTextChanged="Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                        <h5 style="text-align: center;">Cédula &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;Nombres y Apellidos&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;Cargo</h5>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lb_ResultadoFiltro" CssClass="form-control" style="height:400px; min-width: 600px; text-align:center;"  runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="btnGuardarModalResp" CssClass="btn boton" runat="server" Text="Seleccionar" OnClick="btnGuardarModalResp_Click" />
                <button type="button" class="btn boton" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

y la función que intenté programar de AJAX es

```
function filtrar() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Frm_Actas_New.aspx/Modal_txtCedulaResp_TextChanged",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto

```
$(function() {
   $("#dialog").keydown(function(e) {
       $("#tuBoton").trigger("click");
   });
})
```

Comment: No funciona, ¿alguna otra idea?

Comment: Qué no funciona? Puedes aportar más datos? Piensa que lo que he mostrado es una guía. Has puesto un punto de ruptura en ese código y ves si al menos se "para" la ejecución en esa función?